# Importing class into Express.js Route

Tags: typescript, express

My Express src directory looks like this:

```
src
--routes (directory)
--util (directory)
--Server.ts
```

I have classes defined in `util` that I want to use in routes defined in `routes`. However, when I try to import them with this syntax:

```
import className from "../util/className";
```

Express throws this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jasper.huang/Desktop/Personal_Projects/spotify_mtv/api/src/Server.ts:22:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/jasper.huang/Desktop/Personal_Projects/spotify_mtv/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
```

How should I correctly import classes in routes?

Comment: Are you running with ts-node?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922